# JPA/Hibernate How to add duplicate values to a List<> with a @OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting an error every time I try to add duplicate products to the Client class.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_8opk6otadh2pkvi9bghguwp89"
  Detail: Key (products_id)=(500010) already exists.
```

My entities

```
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Product> products;
}

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private Boolean foreign;
    private Integer price;
}
```

When I call `.save()` hibernate is trying to re-save an already existing Product. I believe this is due to the how it cascades things.

```
public Client addNewProduct(Client client, Product newProduct) {
    List<Product> products = client.getProducts();
    products.add(newProduct);
    client.setProducts(products);
    return clientRepository.save(client);
}
```

I just want to be able to add duplicates to a List<>. I believe this is & should be a uni-directional relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work with your current relationship, I don't understand why you would want to add duplicates, but if you have to, then you'd have to create a new entity for that. One example would be something like this:

```java
@Entity
public class ProductBatch {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @OneToOne
  private Product product;

  private Integer count;

  // getter & setter
}
```

and then you change your `Client` like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Client {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<ProductBatch> products;
}
```

this makes something like this possible for your `addNewProduct` function:

```java
public Client addNewProduct(Client client, Product newProduct) {
    List<ProductBatch> products = client.getProducts();
    boolean exists = false;
    for(ProductBatch product : products) {
        if(product.getProduct().equals(newProduct)) {
            product.setCount(product.getCount() + 1);
            exists = true;
        }
    }
    if(!exists) {
        BatchProduct product = new BatchProduct();
        product.setProduct(newProduct);
        product.setCount(0);
        products.add(product);
    }
    client.setProducts(products);
    return clientRepository.save(client);
}
```

Comment: I guess ProductBatch as an intermediate entity would not even be necessary if we just stored Integer count in Product instead ? Or even a Map<Product, Integer> could work ?

Comment: @turbofood the map is unnecessarily complicated to setup and will in the end fill the same purpose as ProductBatch. You cannot store the Integer count in the Product as multiple clients can buy different amounts of one and the same product, so you need an intermediate entity to solve this issue

Comment: Ahh great point. Okay, looks like an intermediate would be needed. Thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with JPA or Hibernate. A constraint is a Database constraint and it is right. If a Foreign Key is already part of the table, trying to add it again, violates this constraint. An ID is unique and it should stay that way. So adding duplicates (at least with the same ID) will not work.

Comment: Then what's the point of even allowing use a of List<> ? Its entirely misleading.